# Where to find good resources to learn XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, silverlight, resources

I'm looking for (online) resources to learn/lookup XAML constructs.

**Can you recommend any good blogs, tutorials, references for XAML?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some more links for knowing about XAML -

> How XAML works :
> http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/446-how-xaml-works.html
>
> The New Iteration(A must read
> whitepaper):
> http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/thenewiteration.aspx

It is also good to have knowledge of BAML(Compiled version of XAML)

> B is for... BAML:
> [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimoneil/b-is-for-baml)
>
> [Compiled XAML = BAML not IL](https://web.archive.org/web/20130813001620/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-_3D00_-BAML-not-IL.aspx)

It may be a little high level but you must know the basic guidelines/conventions (in case you work on a commercial project later):

> XAML Guidelines :
> http://www.cookingwithxaml.com/content/xamlguidelines/xamlGuidelinesDraft0.pdf
>
> XAML Conventions:
> http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/web/wpf-and-xaml-coding-guidelines
>
> XAML guidelines and best practices:
> http://www.85turns.com/2009/02/09/xaml-guidelines-and-best-practices/comment-page-1/#comment-1419

Comment: Thanks for the pointers (especially about the guidelines and conventions).

Answer (score 3):

Well, [MSDN's XAML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) is a pretty good place to start. 
From there, the material discussed in that article is built upon in [XAML Syntax In Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx). 
If you want to go even deeper, you could have a look at the [XAML Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx#the_xaml_language_specification), although the other two articles are probably at the right level of detail to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Best value for the money [XAML (Silverlight QuickStart)](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/xaml/)

Answer (score 1):

While its xaml is specific to Silverlight I thought this was a good resource:

http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/