# Programming GUI elements for time series data

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I am building an GUI application to label time series data. With one track displays the time series data, the other track for the user to interactively label the intervals. I immediately recognize that the GUI of my applicatioin would be very similiar to an audio editing software.

So I opened Audacity and started to think about how to program [its GUI](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Tracks).

My GUI programming abality is limited in using frames, buttons, labels, etc in the toolbox. But I don't know how to program these controls my self. For instance, a label track (see the above link), contains labels in it. The user can also drag the label to other time stamp.

If I want to program similiar GUI elements in .Net, what kind of techniques should I learn? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Going the winforms route, you would create a couple of custom controls (ie the data label, and the label series) that behaves the way you want them to behave and renders the way you want. Here are a couple of links on creating custom controls

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/13/winforms-user-controls-101.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScrollingTextControlArtic.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard you'd be best off learning WPF as it'll give you the quickest route to customising the display of data - however be prepared for a bit of steep learning curve as it's a bit different from the traditional GUI.

If you do learn WPF you may find that the Dynamic Data Display library on codeplex serves as a good point for future customisation.

http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/

many hints for learning wpf here:

[Where to find good resources to learn XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468030/where-to-find-good-resources-to-learn-xaml)
    [Good resources for learning WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526150/good-resources-for-learning-wpf)
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954/what-is-the-best-book-for-learning-wpf

Comment: I don't want dynamic feature, which is too heavy for my application. After trying the sample exectuables, I also find that the exectution speed is too slow compared to Audacity.

Comment: WPF doesn't have to be slow - nor does it have to be slow because it is dynamic - see here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/12/visiblox-visifire-dynamicdatadisplay-charting-performance-comparison/

Comment: btw if the data you are displaying does not contineously change [ie is static] then the application will perform far far faster as it doesn't have to re-layout the data dynamically for each frame. - you can use all of the dynamic data display components with static data if you need to ... it'll be faster